# Unit testing strategy of a Mathematical system like Sage (and MACSYMA, Mathematica)

Tags: testing, sage

To test the correctness and performance of a mathematical system like Sage, do people use a standard test data set of math problems?

If so I'd appreciate a link or reference to the data set.

NOTE:

1. I have taken a look at some of the documents related to testing of Sage like  [Running Sage’s doctests](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/developer/doctesting.html#chapter-doctesting)

Comment: This was also asked at http://ask.sagemath.org/question/31581/test-math-problems-to-test-correctness-of-sage/

Comment: I posted both questions -- is this considered cross-posting (I figured not since they're two different sites)? -- thanks

Comment: I don't think it's a problem, I was just pointing it out for full reference in case it turned out there were useful answers both places.

Comment: oh cool many thanks -- I'll let the questions sit for a bit and I'll try to post notes from each side to the other -- thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot answer regarding Mathematica or Macsyma (or Maple or ...), but both Sage and Maxima have unit tests that are indeed run with each micro-release; however, they are usually not a 'standard' set of problems in either case, though both have some subset thereof.  Depending on the area, some may be part of a standard set - Sage tries to test as many of [Wester's problems](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/master/src/sage/calculus/wester.py) in calculus, and Maxima [does them in all sorts of areas](http://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/code/ci/master/tree/tests/wester_problems/).  Some papers and books have full doctests built into Sage, e.g. [the k-Schur function primer](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/master/src/sage/tests/book_schilling_zabrocki_kschur_primer.py).  But otherwise it just is a set of representative tests in both cases, e.g. [Maxima Lambert W](http://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/code/ci/master/tree/tests/rtest_lambert_w.mac) or [Sage normal form games](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/master/src/sage/game_theory/catalog_normal_form_games.py).

If any such data sets exist, it would be a *very* worthwhile contribution to turn them into a testing file for any given system - [Sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) comes to mind, for instance, as another worthy target.